Warning "No positions in optional float specifier"
I've read the warning and LaTeX documentation of the error message in the title. They are very clear begin{figure}[] with begin{figure}. The warning points towards: ./chapters/Intro/tables/table1.tex
However, here is the MRE of the file referenced:
\begin{table}
    \resizebox{1\linewidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{8cm}}
         \textbf{Column1} & \textbf{Column2}\\
         Item1 & value1 \\
         item2 & value2 \\ 
    \end{tabular}}
    \caption{This is a caption}
    \label{intro-symptoms}
\end{table}

When I remove this table the issue is resolved, but that's not an option.
What causes this warning and how is it resolved?

unrelated but avoid doing \resizebox{1\linewidth}{!}{% it destroys any hope of consistent fonts in the document. But the fragment you show should not give the warning you state please show a complete small example that reproduces the warning.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please extend your code to a minimal working example (MWE).

I understand the drawbacks of resizebox, I manually set the column width to fit the page and only use resizebox to make the table fit the page outline perfectly such that hardly any scaling takes place.

@M.G.Poirot there is no reason to use \resizebox you are setting the width of the table to exactly 12cm+24pt  if that is not equal to \linewidth you should set the columns to different widths, there is no reason to scale afterwards,

You have provided no example, but some code you have not shown is presumably incorrectly redefining table so that the optional argument is no longer optional.
For example this document
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}
               {\@float{table}[]}
               {\end@float}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  t
\end{table}
\end{document}

produces
LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier.
               Default added (so using `tbp') on input line 10.



The error message points towards the table.tex containing the code above, not any figure. Consistently, removing this table resolves the issue. I also don't redefine figure anywhere.

@M.G.Poirot figure/table the same, the answer applies to both.  If the standard definitions are in force then the code you show would give no warning, so the code you have not shown must be defining table  such that it gives a warning. Your question should provide an example that produces a warning, but it will be more or less equivalent to the example I show here,

@M.G.Poirot I edited the answer to use table rather than figure to match your question.
